# How to update a stored procedure in WSO2 Micro Integrator?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have scenario where I'm required to receive data from and endpoint and iterate through while sending it across to another endpoint, take the response and update a stored procedure. So from the data that I receive there is a TableID for each record which is coming from one of the tables of the stored procedure I'm later updating. I can be able do the process from beginning until when I'm supposed to update the stored procedure.

Here is the DBReport I'm using to update the Stored Procedure:

```
            <dbreport>
                <connection>
                    <pool>
                        <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
                        <url>jdbc:sqlserver://1.1.1.1:1433;databaseName=TestingDB;</url>
                        <user>xxxx</user>
                        <password>xxxx</password>
                    </pool>
                </connection>
                <statement>
                    <sql><![CDATA[{CALL SP_UPDATE_TEST_SCENARIO(?,?)}]]></sql>
                    <parameter expression="get-property('TableID')" type="INTEGER"/>
                    <parameter expression="get-property('TestingResponse')" type="VARCHAR"/>
                </statement>
            </dbreport>
```

Comment: So what's your issue?

Comment: The query I have inserts instead of updating the record based on the 'TableID', Is there something I'm doing wrong maybe?